# RubyonRails Guide confusion over link creation in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am a beginner to Rails. Was working along with Railsguide for Rails 4.

One confusion i have is:
 for adding a link , somewhere it is written like:

```
 <h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
   <%= link_to "My Blog", controller: "posts" %>
```

whereas somewhere its like

```
  <%= link_to 'New post', new_post_path %>
```

Please clarify the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Both of these are link helpers, and both are **resource-oriented** (check out the [Rails UrlHelper docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html) for more information).

The first one will render a link that is associated with the particular controller:

```
<%= link_to "My Blog", controller: "posts" %>
<a href='/posts'>
```

The second will render the Rails path specific to creating a new Post object (this is also resource-oriented). Check out section 2.3 in the Rails [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers):

```
<%= link_to 'New post', new_post_path %>
<a href='/posts/new'>
```

Comment: can I write this?

<%= link_to "My Blog", posts_path %>